# combobox search invalidargument=value of '0' is not valid for 'index'. parameter name index vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i am using a textbox to search in an access database and then to show the matches in combobox , it is working fine but there is an error accrued when the user enters not matched entry ,

this is my code :

```
Private Sub TextBox9_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox9.TextChanged
    Try
        ComboBox3.DataSource = Me.MyDataset.Items.Select("ItemName like '%" & TextBox9.Text & "%'")


        ComboBox3.Update()

        If ComboBox3.Items.Count <> 0 Then

            ComboBox3.DroppedDown = True
            Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
            Cursor.Show()
        Else

            If ComboBox3.DroppedDown = True Then
                ComboBox3.DroppedDown = False
            End If

        End If

        If TextBox9.Text = "" Then
            ComboBox3.DroppedDown = False
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical Or MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")
    End Try
End Sub
```

and when the user enters wrong entry or not matched this error appear :
invalidargument=value of '0' is not valid for 'index'. parameter name index vb.net

the question is how to handle this error

Comment: Code tip: `If ComboBox3.DroppedDown = True Then` should just be `If ComboBox3.DroppedDown Then`.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if your datasource contains items before binding them to the ComboBox.

I don't know what type `MyDataset` is, but with `Option Infer On` the following should work, otherwise you should change the `Dim dataSource =` line to include the type.

```
    Private Sub TextBox9_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox9.TextChanged
        Try

            Dim dataSource = Me.MyDataset.Items.Select("ItemName like '%" & TextBox9.Text & "%'")

            If dataSource.Items.Count > 0 Then
                ComboBox3.DataSource = datasource
                ComboBox3.Update()
            End If

            If ComboBox3.Items.Count <> 0 Then
                ComboBox3.DroppedDown = True
                Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
                Cursor.Show()
            Else
                If ComboBox3.DroppedDown = True Then
                    ComboBox3.DroppedDown = False
                End If
            End If

            If TextBox9.Text = "" Then
                ComboBox3.DroppedDown = False
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical Or MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")
        End Try
    End Sub
```